# Logic issue between two classes

Tags: recursion

I'm coding a classic Sokoban game. I've got a class named **"Warehouse"** which represents a warehouse and a class named **"WarehouseItem"** which is a base class for items that belong to the warehouse.

I would like the following operations to be possible:

```vb
Dim wh as Warehouse
Dim whItem as WarehouseItem

wh.Add(whItem)
wh.Remove(whItem)
whItem.Warehouse = wh
whItem.Warehouse = Nothing
```

The problem is that I end up with the functions above trying to call each other recursively and I don't know how to obey it (and where I am making the mistake). Here's how it looks like:

```vb
Class Warehouse
    ...
    Items as List(Of WarehouseItem)        

    Sub Add(item as WarehouseItem)
         Items.Add(item)
         wh.Warehouse = wh // Recursive call
    End Sub
    ...
 End Class

Class WarehouseItem
    ...   
    Private mWarehouse as Warehouse

    Property Warehouse As Warehouse
        ...
        Set(wh As Warehouse)
             mWarehouse = wh 
             mWarehouse.Add(me) // Recursive call
        End Set
    End Property
    ...
 End Class
```

I would appreciate any advices on how can I change the code so the above operations are possible to execute.

Comment: This is a very common beginner problem in object-oriented programming in general and not specific to game development.

Answer (score 2):

You have an endless recursion. A calls B, and B calls A, which calls B again ... You need to break this up somehow. Generally, what you do is make `WarehouseItem.Warehouse` private (or at least read-only), so people *always* have to go through `Warehouse.Add` to add a `WarehouseItem`. That means that you don't have to override `Set` for `WarehouseItem.Warehouse` anymore, so it won't call `Warehouse.Add` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each function will always call the other one. You should be checking to see if the `WarehouseItem` has already been added to the `Items` of the `Warehouse`, and only add it if it's not:

```
Class Warehouse
    ...
    Items as List(Of WarehouseItem)        

    Sub Add(item as WarehouseItem)
         If Not Items.Contains(item) Then
             Items.Add(item)
             wh.Warehouse = wh
         End If 
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

You'll need to make sure that a `WarehouseItem` overloads the operator for Equals, otherwise Contains won't give you what you want:

```
Class WarehouseItem
...
    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As WarehouseItem) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of WarehouseItem).Equals
        If other Is Nothing Then 
            Return False 
        End If 
        Return (Me.Id.Equals(other.Id)) //or whatever makes warehouseparts equal
    End Function
```

Now if you call Warehouse.Add(WarehouseItem) the first time, it will add it, and call WarehouseItem.Set(Warehouse). Warehouse.Add is then called again, but will not do anything since the item has already been added.